# Odd output when trying to set up Flask secret key

Tags: python, flask, byte

I'm trying to work out how to deploy a Flask app. [The docs](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/1.0/tutorial/deploy/#configure-the-secret-key) say I can generate a secret key with a Python command:

```
python -c 'import os; print(os.urandom(16))'
```

In their example this outputs `b'_5#y2L"F4Q8z\n\xec]/'`.

When I run it with `python` I get odd characters, and with `python3` I get character codes. Why are the `python` and `python3` versions different? Which one should I use?

```
$ python -c 'import os; print(os.urandom(16))' 
��L���vl�6��Z5

$ python3 -c 'import os; print(os.urandom(16))'
b'A\xa4\xf3O\xdd\xf4qr\xfb\x9b\x12\x1f*\x0bm\xdf'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be using Python 3 for all new projects, so this is essentially a non-issue. The Python 3 output is correct and can be copy pasted directly. The fact that `python` runs Python 2 for you means you have not followed the tutorial to set up a Python 3 virtualenv, or your virtualenv is not active.

If you're really using Python 2 for some reason, that output is fine too. Copy and paste it into quotes and it will work. Python 2's `str` is sort-of-bytes, so it outputs non-ASCII characters, while Python 3 always outputs bytes with escape characters (`\xAB`). Either output will work in either version.

```
SECRET_KEY = '��L���vl�6��Z5'
SECRET_KEY = b'A\xa4\xf3O\xdd\xf4qr\xfb\x9b\x12\x1f*\x0bm\xdf'
```

The example output does contain escape characters (`\n` and `\xec`), just not as many as the random string you happened to generate.